# MySQL Foreign Keys error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a self join table with varchars as the primary key and foreign keys. The table creates but I keep receiving errors when trying to insert data into the table

Table

```
 CREATE TABLE `staff` (
`staff_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`manager_id` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`))
```

Data dump

```
   /*Data for the table `staff` */
  INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
  VALUES ('lo1234', 'test','**.com', null);
 INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
  VALUES ('er8909', 'test2','**.com', 'l01234');
 INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
 VALUES ('ru6758', 'r**','**.com', 'l01234');
 INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
 VALUES ('ad4567', 'admin','**.com', null);
```

Is there something wrong with the construction of the schema or the data being inserted?

Comment: Why are you doing this `FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id))` ?

Comment: @EdHeal: it's a reference to the same table, establishing a connection to the person (staff member) who is the manager of that person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong at this line make `1o1234` to `1012345`, as

```
INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
          VALUES ('lo1234', 'test','**.com', null);
```

change this to this:

```
INSERT INTO staff (STAFF_ID, NAME, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID)
  VALUES ('l01234', 'test','**.com', null);
```

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing the error. I changed it to the lo1234 value and it worked.